# get several integer numbers with c++-CIN and put them into array

Tags: c++, arrays, input, cin

i need to get couple integer numbers and put them into an array in c++.
assume the count of numbers in `CIN` are the same count as array length.

```
int numbers[10];
cin>>numbers;
```

In fact i want to enter 10 numbers to `cin` within one line somehow it automatically allocates the numbers to array. how should i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a C++11 solution using `std::vector` and `std::copy_n`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 3, std::back_inserter(v));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a loop:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int numbers[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cin >> numbers[i];
}
```

UPDATE:

If it has to be **one line** then you could use this (somewhat clumsy solution):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int numbers[3];
    std::cin >> numbers[0] >> numbers[1] >> numbers[2];
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::cin.getline` and then parse the string.

UPDATE (again):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int numbers[3];
    int* input = numbers;
    while (std::cin >> *input++ and input != 3 + numbers) ;
}
```

Comment: Is it always 10 elements?

Comment: yes. i have a fixed array. not 10 but maybe more. but i have the size of that before call CIN

Comment: as i said. i can not say number[1] , .... i need something dynamic not to mention index of array 1 and 2 and so on

Comment: @MehrdadDadvand Is the while-loop-solution any better?